# Root composer.json requires dev-master found dev-main on Docker

Tags: docker, symfony, composer-php

I create a local repository of type "path" in composer like this:

```
   {
     ...
     "whweb/core-bundle": "dev-master"
     ...
   }
   ... 
   "repositories": [{
    "type": "path",
    "url" : "../wh-web-lib/whweb/core-bundle",
    "options": {
        "symlink": false
    }
    }]
    ...
```

when I run **composer install or update** on my local computer all ok (works)
as soon as docker copies the project to a linux container, including the wh-web-lib folder, **composer update or install** fails with the following error:

```
Root composer.json requires whweb/core-bundle dev-master, found whweb/core-bundle[dev-main] but it does not match your constraint and is therefore not installable
```

Why is not working ? Is there a way to make it working equally well when it's on my local computer and when it runs on docker Linux container ?

Answer (score 0):

might be solved with something like `export COMPOSER_ROOT_VERSION=dev-master`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32233757)

Comment: @programmerq this looks like an honest attempt to answer the question to me... it could use some explanation about *why* this could work, but that doesn't make it less valid if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Is the volume mapped in Docker? Maybe ../wh-web-lib isn't mapped into the container. You can `docker exec [container name] /bin/sh` and look for the folder.